# Symfony2 beginner - suggest small application idea to cover more complicated aspects of framework?

Tags: symfony

A trainee has just started at the company I work for. He'll be working on a big Symfony2 project with me, however, before he gets started on the project, I would like him to complete a little application that uses many of the symfony components/options.

At the moment, we have already created a little blog together. After generating the bundle, an entity and a form from the command line we started working on putting together a frontend to the app. The pages include:

- List of posts
- Create post
- Delete post
- Edit post

This was good to get a general idea of where things are placed in the framework and how controller, views and routes work.

But now I would like him to cover the more complicated aspects of the framework i.e. the lifecycle callbacks, entity relationships, custom forms, authentication, twig extensions, assetic, DQL etc. i.e. stuff that hasn't been auto-generated.

For you, what would be a good little application to ask someone to make that would cover the more complicated aspects of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a Tag entity with a ManyToMany relation with Post and then implement suitable functionality.  ManyToMany relations can be challenging.
2. Implement an ACL type system such that a user can edit their own posts while moderators can edit all posts.  This will take them through the security system.
3. And then if you really want to test him, have him wrap everything up in a simple step by step tutorial and publish it.  S2 still does not have many up to date introductory tutorials.